# Is stdbuf preferred to reduce pipe data flow?

Tags: bash, performance, io, pipe, centos7

If one has a piped command such as:

```
a | b | c
```

and I want to reduce unnecessary data flow across the pipes, would I use [stdbuf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf):

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0
```

in front of:

- the first command?
- the last command?
- every command?

As in:

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 a | b | c
a | b | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 c
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 a | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 b | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 c
```

Let's assume that the command `c` is the one that terminates first as concerns `SIGPIPE` behavior.

Is `stdbuf` preferred to `unbuffer`? Are the options used above appropriate? Are other approaches superior in terms of performance and code maintainability?

**Notes:** This question applies to:

- Bash 4.2 and higher
- Red Hat 7, CentOS 7, and related distros (that is, not Debian, etc.)
- No third-party software should be used. Packages must be available, for example, via OS-provider packages in the [CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1611.iso](http://ftp.linux.ncsu.edu/pub/CentOS/7.3.1611/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1611.iso) repository iso (and similarly for RHEL 7, Fedora 7, etc).

Comment: Could you define what you mean by " reduce unnecessary data flow".  The amount of actual data will not be affected, there will be one more process, but there would be smaller buffers.  Is that your intent?

Comment: Just to be clear, avoiding buffers may reduce memory usage, but will increase the load on the CPU.  What are you trying to optimize?

Comment: There is no "unneccessary" data flow; the OS manages the buffer between the two processes already. If `a` writes faster than `b` can read, the buffer will fill up and `a` will block until `b` can read more. If `a` writes slower than `b` can read, `b` will block until data is available.

Comment: Everything coming out of `a` on `stdout` goes into `b` and everything coming out of `b` on `stdout` goes into `c`. There is no unnecessary flow.

Comment: Buffering is there for a reason, generally for efficient use of CPU.  There are some edge cases where switching off buffering is desirable, for example when debugging, this is why by default on most systems `stderr` is unbuffered.  In general switching off buffering will result in worse performance, although in many scenarios there won't be a measurable difference.   `stdbuf` is non-standard, and will not affect programs which don't use streams:  see `man stdbuf`.

Comment: Thanks for the many comments. If there are a lot of data to process, can't this slow down the overall performance? For example, if `a` generates data very slowly, does `b` have to wait until the buffer is flushed before it can begin processing? And, similarly, if `b` is computationally slow. And if `c` is something as simple as a function that terminates after a small number of bytes are read, forcing `a` and `b` to terminate, the concern is that the buffering in the preceding commands unnecessarily slows down the entire processing time as observed by a user. Can this happen?

Comment: @Fred _reduce unnecessary data flow_: some data from `a` is unused by `b` or `c` because `c` terminates after it has enough data to conclude, so the goal is to not delay the processing just to get a full buffer of data because most of that data is going to be discarded. I'm assuming that the reason for existence for commands such as `stdbuf` and `unbuffer` is to address exactly this need. Thoughts?

Comment: It depends on the program and the way that the pipes are used.  Usually *line buffering* is in use, that is the buffer is flushed on a newline, and many programs need a full line on input before they can process anything.  There is a C system constant called `PIPE_BUF` which specifies the maximum buffer size, but I doubt that will be in use here.  Can you say which programs are going to be used?

Comment: @cdarke My specific application is that the `a` command is a function that generates a stream of bytes that are being used for cryptographic reasons. There are no newlines in the data. The `b` command is also a function that does a transformation on the bytes received from `a`. And the `c` command reads a specified number of bytes (for example, 64) and then echos them and exits.